# Why is this program failing to pick up my voice?

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a question for the community. I followed some somewhat recent tutorial on a speech-to-text kinda deal. It worked for him and not for me, so do you have any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
namespace Voice_Recognition
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        btnEnable.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] {"say hello", "print my name" });
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += RecEngine_SpeechRecognized;



    }

    private void RecEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text)
        {
            case "say hello":
                MessageBox.Show("Hello, Zach!");

                break;
            case "print my name":
                richTextBox1.Text += "\n Zach";

                break;
        }
    }

    private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        btnDisable.Enabled = false;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the Load event wired?  That code should probably be in the constructor anyway.

Comment: Try awaiting your async calls, my guess is maybe you are not awaiting and hence there are are some processes not being able to execute properly. It would also be helpful if you could post the link to the tutorial so that one can get a better understanding.

Comment: The tutorial that was used was: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AB9lfHDOe5U